# Java Nonworking method?

Tags: java

Hey,
So Ive got this method to determine if a game I wrote is over and for some reason it isn't working. I'm getting the error "the left hand side of assignment must be a variable"

Here is the method:

```
public boolean isWinner() {//checks for game completion
     int check = board[startX][startY];
     for(int i=0; i<sizeX; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<sizeY; j++){
           if (board[i][j] != check)
              return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
  }
```

Here is a piece of the code where it is used:

```
ColorFloodGame game = new ColorFloodGame (6,6);        
while (game.isWinner() = false){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: can you post error code? What kind of "non-working" is this?

Comment: For such short pieces of code it would be **much** better to post them directly here (make sure to use the code formatting feature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
while (game.isWinner() = false){
```

with

```
while (game.isWinner() == false){
```

or better yet:

```
while (!game.isWinner()){
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `while (game.isWinner() = false)`, which is an assignment because you have a single `=` sign.

You want `while (game.isWinner() == false)` which is a comparison because it has two `=` signs.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (game.isWinner() = false){
```

should be

```
while (game.isWinner() == false){
```

one '=' is an assignment, two '==' is a comparison

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that

Answer (score 1):

Ralf & Gabe have already answered it, but IMHO this is more readable:

```
while (!game.isWinner()){
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the while statement is an assignment. The compiler can't evaluate the expression correctly. Change your code to the following and everything should work fine.

```
while (game.isWinner() == false) {
    //code here
}
```

You could also write the code like this

```
while (!game.isWinner()) {
    //code here
}
```

The style used is different for every programmer and you should find your own preference.

Hope it helps.